# Kubernetes Delete Persistent Voulmes Created by hostPath

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a PV and a PVC on docker-desktop and even after removing the pv and pvc the file still remains. When I re-create it, it attaches the same mysql database to new pods. How do you manually delete the files created by the hostPath? I suppose one way is to just reset Kubernetes in the preferences but there has to be another less nuclear option.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim2
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Comment: I found a good solution with docker-desktop. If you use /tmp or create a new share drive with docker for desktop you can go in and manually delete the files. I had expected that when you delete the volume it deletes the data but that's not the case with local and hostPath volumes.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#recycle), "...`Recycle` reclaim policy performs a basic scrub (`rm -rf /thevolume/*`) on the volume and makes it available again for a new claim". [Also](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaim-policy), "...Currently, only NFS and HostPath support recycling". So, try changing

```
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
```

to

```
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
```

Answer (score 3):

`hostPath` volumes are simply folders on one of your node's filesystem (in this case `/mnt/data`). All you need to do is delete that folder from the node that hosted the volume.

Comment: that part makes sense, where I'm stuck is how to I get to the node? I know in windows docker runs on a linux vm from hyper-v. Happen to know where it runs from in macOS?

Comment: @duffney I am not familiar with those systems, do you know if ssh is installed on your node?

Comment: I don't think so, I can't access by the name and IP shown with kubeclt cmds. I posed it in docker's forms. There has to be a way to access the hose created inside docker-desktop. https://forums.docker.com/t/kubernetes-delete-hostpath-files-docker-desktop/81526

Answer (score 1):

If you defined any node affinity to pod that you need to check. Then find out node where that pod is schedule. Delete `PVC` an `PV` Then delete data from /mnt/data directory.

`kubectl get pod -o wide | grep <pod_name>`

Here you will get on which node it is scheduled.

`kubectl delete deploy or statefulset <deploy_name>`

`kubectl get pv,pvc`

`kubectl delete pv <pv_name>`

`kubectl delete pvc <pvc_name>`

Now go on that node and delete that data from `/mnt/data`

One more way to do it you can define `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy`
to `retain` or `delete`